# Insert not inserting all

Tags: mysql

Following is my query in which I am trying to insert those records whose name doesnot exist in food (insertion table) .  For id generation i am trying to get the count from `food` and adding one to it `COUNT( food.FOOd_id ) +1 eg. Chineese_01` and then comparing the name coming from `pick` table with foodname of `food` table. In order to allow inseertion for those names which doesnot already exist. The following query gives right result but it make insertion once (one row) and when i run it again it again makes one insertion and so on. Kindly let me know how can i modify the following query so it should make insertion for all. Thanks

```
    INSERT IGNORE into food(FOOD_id,FOOD_name)
    Select CONCAT(  FOOD,"_", COUNT( food.FOOd_id ) +1 ),CONCAT(  Typ,CONCAT('(' ,family,')' )) from pick,food
    where CONCAT(  Typ,CONCAT('(' ,family,')' )) NOT IN (Select FOOD_name from food )
```

**SQL FIDDLE:** (For testing and making the right query)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91408/1

Comment: Can you post your schema for these 2 tables?

Comment: @PinnyM okay let me crete on sqlfiddle

Comment: Please look here for a answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869475/is-there-any-way-to-check-whether-or-not-the-query-inside-a-mysql-trigger-return/13875059#13875059

Comment: @PinnyM  kindly take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91408/1

Comment: Do you have control over revising this schema?  It's not the best way to represent this data, to say the least...

Comment: @PinnyM well actually solving this issue will gonna solve the problem of my actual schema. ITs not what i am actually working on i simplified it here

Comment: Except the new `food_id` is still a complex field.  Instead of language and name it has language and arbitrary number.  A general rule of thumb is that if you're concatenating values to insert them into a table, you might be doing something wrong.  Here, the language and the number should be separate fields, and the key should be a combination of the language and the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `COUNT()` in the SELECT clause is forcing aggregation, so only one row will be selected.  You need to either specify a grouping, or move it to a subquery.  Adding this to the bottom of the query is one way to solve it:

```
GROUP BY pick.food, pick.typ, pick.family
```

Comment: Correct, Why the `COUNT( food.FOOd_id ) +1` is not working? like it inserted the rows but all have the same ids i.e `ENG_4`

Comment: This is because `COUNT` is evaluated once when the SELECT is run.  The INSERT takes place after the result set is built from the SELECT query.  I don't think you'll be able to use `COUNT` to do what you need here without involving temp tables or a number generating function/view.