# Eliminating duplicate entries while uploading excel files to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, upload, phpexcel

I am working on an application where the website admin can upload excel sheets to upload data to the database. Offcourse I use [this](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) excellent library for uploading files to my mysql database.

**Issue:** It all works fine,but the issue now is,if the admin uploads a list,I have to show the admin the uploaded data on a page and ask him to confirm the upload by hitting a button.Till the confirmation point I store the data in a temporary table in the DB.Once the admin confirms,I move it to the permanent table in DB and delete the entries in the temporary table.Now if the admin edits the same excel,i.e he adds some more records to it and uploads it again,the previous records get **duplicated**,which should not happen.

I want to check if the records from the excel file already exists(based on a unique `id` that is associated with each record). This is not the primary key but a no. associated with each record present in DB and the excel sheet.

I am looking for suggestion on how can I check if the record already exists as I delete the temporary table info. Can I compare the temp table data(**if not deleted**)with the file data each time its uploaded?**How can I check if the file records are similar to the once in the database and upload only newly added records?**.

Any suggestions,would be helpful  to go the right way .
Thank you for the attention

Comment: If you have stored the records in a temp table, you can run an inner join query to identify duplicate records and either highlight to the user or auto delete as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To identify new records use a left or right join(your preference) on the temp and permanent tables to  insert the new records into the permanent tables. You can also use this technique to determine if you need to delete records from the permanent tables.

The use a inner join to execute a update the records currently in the database as @Pynner pointed out in his earlier comment.

See this answer for a explanation of how to use left and right join etc [Is there any way to check whether or not the query inside a MySQL trigger returns an empty set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869475/is-there-any-way-to-check-whether-or-not-the-query-inside-a-mysql-trigger-return/13875059#13875059)

Comment: Will check it and revert.Thank you for the response!

Comment: Working on some other stuff.Will definitely accept the answer once I try it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use insert ignore which will ignore duplicate record provided appropriate unique index is applied. this will ignore already inserted entries and add only new entries. this is what u want i guess

All you need to do is instead of 
    INSERT INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(val1,val2);
do 
    INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl_name (col1,col2) VALUES(val1,val2);
This should stop the duplicate and only insert new entries. Please note this relies on proper indexing applied.

Comment: Can you elaborate and share a link for the example?