# Number of OR conditions in SQL/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Does anyone know what the maximum number of `OR` conditions that I can set in single query for MySQL and MSSQL DBMS?

Comment: Why do you want to know this information?  Would an `in` clause be useful to replace a bunch of `or`s?

Comment: Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264852/having-a-lot-of-sql-query-conditions

Comment: MySQL has a max packet size if you use a IN clause like Gordan Linoff says you should pass in more information.

Comment: I am planning to use IN condition, but my idea is to selects ID's from one database (there are more than 50000 products) and to delete from another using IN clause. The question is can delete work with  sub-query that have so much ID's?

Comment: A `JOIN` operation is usually more efficient than a subquery. If you are using a SELECT statement to derive a list of ID's to delete, that same query can usually be used as an inline view. If you are transporting that to a different database platform, then loading that list into a work table would probably be much more efficient than SQL statement(s) with boatloads of literals.

Answer (score 0):

From the info in your comments just use a sub query.  For example:

```
delete tblCustomers
where CustomerId in (select CustomerId from tblOtherTable)
```

**UPDATE**
There are only 2 possible approaches given your situation.

1. Export data from MSSQL.  Then import that data into a temporary table in your MySQL server.  After that import, run a query like the above one.
2. Write a C# app that pulls all the values you want and runs a set of INSERT/UPDATE queries against your MySQL database.

The first option is by far the best because it is fairly simple and will run fast.  The second option isn't that great because it means you will be executing 2 queries for every record in your MSSQL server. (One to find out if the record is there, followed by either an INSERT or UPDATE statement on the MySQL server.

Comment: Yes, but these databases are on different location and they are different systems. One is MSSQL other is MySQL. One is in the office, other is on web.

Comment: I'm failing to see the problem.  The data has to be accessible in some way, whether that is through a linked server OR by exporting from one and importing into another.  Certainly this is far easier than running a bunch of delete statements.

Comment: Well help me a bit: read my question here first please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264852/having-a-lot-of-sql-query-conditions and try to understand my situation.

Answer (score 0):

In **MySQL**, the number of `OR` conditions that can be included in a SQL statement is limited by the maximum length of a SQL statement, which is limited by the `max_allowed_packet` variable setting.

SHOW VARIABLE LIKE 'max_allowed_packet`

(Note: the value for `max_allowed_packet` is specified in bytes not characters, something to be aware of if your SQL statement includes multi-byte characters).

When faced with creating a statement with a large list of `OR` conditions, there is usually a different way to perform the same operation, such as an `IN (list)` or a `JOIN` operation.

A more efficient approach in MySQL is going to be create a table and load it from a file. (The "big rock" difficulty with this approach is going to be getting the characterset encodings to be compatible.)

If you can produce a .CSV file from SQL Server (with one line per ID to be deleted) in either a latin1 or utf8 encoding, then characterset matching is more of a speed bump than a boulder.

On the MySQL side:

```
CREATE TABLE ids_to_delete (id INT PRIMARY KEY);

LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/ids_to_delete.csv' INTO TABLE ids_to_delete
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
  IGNORE 1 LINES;

-- rows to be deleted (save a backup of this if you don't already have a mysqldump)
SELECT t.id
  FROM my_target_table t
  JOIN ids_to_delete d
    ON d.id = t.id ;

-- perform the delete
-- DELETE t.*
--   FROM my_target_table t
--      JOIN ids_to_delete d
--   ON d.id = t.id ;
```

---

For loading just character representation of unsigned integer values (`^[0-9]*$`), there shouldn't be any problem with translation. The encoding for digit characters '0' thru '9' are x'30' thru x'39', and the windows style CR+LF is x'0d0a', for both latin1 and utf8.

Comment: I see. Well are queries UNICODE or ANSI encoding? I am asking because I want to calculate maximum number of conditions (in characters) that I can set.

Comment: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'character%'` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character%' will show the database characterset and your client characterset. (latin1 is a single byte characterset, utf8 uses one byte for character for most common characters, but two or more bytes for the more esoteric characters.)